# Return a promise of a promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm quite new to Angular, but I'm trying to find out some things.

I do have a method which returns a promise:

```
preloaderServiceObject.Load = function(referencePaths){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $(referencePaths).each(function(index, referencePath) {
        var preloadedElement = document.createElement('img');
        {
            preloadedElement.onload = deferred.resolve;
            preloadedElement.src = referencePath;
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

This is all working fine and doesn't cause the problem.
However, I do have another method which should return a promise inside the completion call of the promise, like so:

```
OfficeUIRibbonControlServiceObject.Initialize = function(configurationFile) {
    $http.get(configurationFile)
        .then(function (response) {
            $rootScope.Tabs = response.data.Tabs;
            $rootScope.ContextualGroups = response.data.ContextualGroups;

            var images = JSPath.apply('.Groups.Areas.Actions.Resource', $rootScope.Tabs);
            images.concat(JSPath.apply('.Tabs.Groups.Areas.Actions.Resource', $rootScope.ContextualGroups));

            PreloaderService.Load(images);
        });
}
```

The last line `PreloaderService.Load(images);` does return a promise as defined in the first function in this post.

But, now I want to call the method `OfficeUIRibbonControlServiceObject.Initialize', but how should i change this method so that I can wait for until the loading of the PreloaderService has been completed?

Just changing the method to return that promise will not work, because the returned object will be undefined (since I'm in the `then` method of the $http.

Kind regards,

**Edit**: As suggested by Rouby, using a promise:

The initialize function:

```
OfficeUIRibbonControlServiceObject.Initialize = function(configurationFile) {
    $http.get(configurationFile)
        .then(function (response) {
            $rootScope.Tabs = response.data.Tabs;
            $rootScope.ContextualGroups = response.data.ContextualGroups;

            var images = JSPath.apply('.Groups.Areas.Actions.Resource', $rootScope.Tabs);
            images.concat(JSPath.apply('.Tabs.Groups.Areas.Actions.Resource', $rootScope.ContextualGroups));

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            PreloaderService.Load(images).then(function() {
                deferred.resolve();
            });

            return deferred;
        });
}
```

The InitializeService method:

```
function InitializeService(serviceInstance, configurationFile) {
    serviceInstance.Initialize(configurationFile).then(function() {
        console.log('This method has been called.');
    });
}
```

The result of this is that I get: `Error: serviceInstance.Initialize(...) is undefined`

Comment: You need to create the deferred in the scope of the Initialize function

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @Rouby That seems to work. Put the definition of the deferred as the first line, resolve it in the then() function of the `Load` method and then return it as the last statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new deferred in `.Initialize` that gets resolved when the second `.Load` finishes, you can then return this deferred as normal.

E.g.

```
PreloaderService.Load(images).then(function(){ newDeferred.resolve(); }, function(){ newDeferred.reject(); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I'm quite new to AngularJS. You mind explaining it a bit more?

Comment: I think this has nothing in special to do with Angular, but more with promises. What exactly do you need explained further?

Comment: How to work exactely with the deferred. I'm new to it and the terms doesn't say me much.

Comment: I've mentioned above what I've done in the EDIT part of my question. Could you have a look because it's still not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've accepted your answer as it seems to work. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Better return the promise:

```
OfficeUIRibbonControlServiceObject.Initialize = function(configurationFile) {
return $http.get(configurationFile)
    .then(function (response) {
        $rootScope.Tabs = response.data.Tabs;
        $rootScope.ContextualGroups = response.data.ContextualGroups;

        var images = JSPath.apply('.Groups.Areas.Actions.Resource', $rootScope.Tabs);
        images.concat(JSPath.apply('.Tabs.Groups.Areas.Actions.Resource', $rootScope.ContextualGroups));

        return PreloaderService.Load(images);
    });
```

}

When you now call the `OfficeUIRibbonControlServiceObject.Initialize` function the **result** from `PreloaderService.Load` will be returned.

example:

```
OfficeUIRibbonControlServiceObject.Initialize(// myConfiguration //).then (
    function success (response) {
       console.log("promise success", response)
    },
    function fail (error) {
       console.log("promise fail", error) // the result from PreloaderService.Load
    }
 );
```

In general: you can return values or promises in the `.then` function. When you return a promise. The resolve value of that promise will be returned after that promise is resolved

Comment: I believe there should be a `return ` before `$http.get` too.

Comment: When I execute this, the following call `serviceInstance.Initialize(configurationFile)` will result in an unidentified object.

Comment: Thanks Chandermani, the function should return the http.get promise. I edit the answer